# Device does not have enough capacity to power a USB external HDD

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, power-supply, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to connect my USB 3.0 External HDD to Raspberry Pi. However the HDD spins for a few seconds and stop.

I think the Pi does not have enough capacity to power the HDD.

What are my options?

Comment: USB powered hub

Comment: USB Y cable....

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @DavidPostill. Basically you'd either need a USB powered hub, or something like WD PiDrive kit. Anyway an externally powered USB hub is always a good idea with Rpi as this will exclude the need for more power if you decide to add more peripheral devices at some point, which will also need more power.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the Pi does not have enough capacity to power the HDD.
>   What are my options?

- Use a case with its own powersupply (most external HDD cases I saw have sunch an option, but are sold without PSU).
- Use a HDD whch requires less power.
- Use an USB2 hub with its own power supply. This **might** work, especially in combination with an Y-cable. It does not address the problem that USB2 only delivers electric current up to 500 mA (2.5 W of power) and that the drive draws more, but you should be able to tap an extra 500mA per Y.
- Use an USB3 hub with its own power supply. USB3 is allow to deliver 900mA of current if asked. This assumed that the case is also USB3.

Regardless of option choosen, drawing a lot of power via the Pi is not the recommende way. Feeding the drive dirextly seems better (read: use a powersupply to the external case)>

Comment: There is little to no technical reason why the Raspberry Pi can't provide sufficient current for USB, maybe except their poor choice of power supply connector. The Pi is not a battery-powered device, and they supply the kits with 2.4A wall adapters. If self-powered hubs do the full power all the time, why not the Raspberry-Pi, which has exactly the same form-factor and power delivery architecture as most hubs?

Comment: The choice for the power connector makes sense if you want to go as cheap as possible and reuse existing phone-chargers. But only using that and no other power supply also means pushing all the current though the rPi board. I am not sure that that is a great idea. If possible I would split the power from the PSU before it goes to the rPi and the disk. Then again, that is 'seems a better idea' vs 'more cost' again.